# Removing lines from a string containing certain character

Tags: java, string

I am working a Java project to read a java class and extract all DOC comments into an HTML file. I am having trouble cleaning a string of the lines I don't need.

Lets say I have a string such as:

```
"/**
* Bla bla
*bla bla
*bla bla
*/

CODE
CODE
CODE

/**
* Bla bla
*bla bla
*bla bla
*/ "
```

I want to remove all the lines not starting with `*`.

Is there any way I can do that?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

First, you should split your `String` into a `String[]` on line breaks using `String.split(String)`. Line breaks are usually `'\n'` but to be safe, you can get the system line separator using `System.getProperty("line.separator");`.

The code for splitting the `String` into a `String[]` on line breaks can now be

```
String[] lines = originalString.split(System.getProperty("line.separator"));
```

With the String split into lines, you can now check if each line starts with `*` using `String.startsWith(String prefix)`, then make it an empty string if it does.

```
for(int i=0;i<lines.length;i++){
    if(lines[i].startsWith("*")){
        lines[i]="";
    }
}
```

Now all you have left to do is to combine your `String[]` back into a single `String`

```
StringBuilder finalStringBuilder= new StringBuilder("");
for(String s:lines){
   if(!s.equals("")){
       finalStringBuilder.append(s).append(System.getProperty("line.separator"));
    }
}
String finalString = finalStringBuilder.toString();
```

Comment: StringBuilder finalStringBuilder= new StringBuilder("");

Comment: Thanks, that made the job for me, however code can be factorized, I posted an answer with what I've done

Answer (score 1):

Yes Java's String class has a startsWith() method that returns a boolean. You can iterate through each line in the file and check if each line starts with "*" and if it does delete it.

Try this:

```
File inputFile = new File("myFile.txt");
File tempFile = new File("myTempFile.txt");

BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(inputFile));
BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(tempFile));

String linesToRemoveStartsWith = "*";
String currentLine;

while((currentLine = reader.readLine()) != null) {
    // trim newline when comparing with lineToRemove
    String trimmedLine = currentLine.trim();
    if(!trimmedLine.startsWith(linesToRemoveStartsWith )) continue;
    writer.write(currentLine + System.getProperty("line.separator"));
}
writer.close(); 
reader.close(); 
boolean successful = tempFile.renameTo(inputFile);
```

Comment: Ohhh this helps a lot. ill get started on it immediately. Thanks a lot!

Comment: No problem. If the solution works for you, could you mark the answer as useful and/or accepted.

Comment: I just noticed, but this removes lines starting with "*" I want to remove all other lines. Is there a way i can do that or simply write those lines to another string (if that is easier) ?

Comment: Change `if(trimmedLine.startsWith(linesToRemoveStartsWith )) continue;` to `if(!trimmedLine.startsWith(linesToRemoveStartsWith )) continue;` i.e. just add a `!` before `trimmedLine.startsWith(linesToRemoveStartsWith )`.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I remember, you cannot delete lines from the text documents in-place in Java. So, you would have to copy the needed lines into a new file. Or, if you need to output the same file, just changed, you could read the data into memory, delete the file, create a new one with the same name and only output the needed lines. Although, frankly, for me it seems a bit silly.

Answer (score 0):

A shorter version of Jason Slobotski's answer:

```
final StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
// Loop on original string lines by splitting it with line separator
for (final String line : originalString.split(System.lineSeparator())) {
    if (!line.startsWith("*")) {
        // Add only lines that does not start with '*'
        stringBuilder.append(line).append(System.lineSeparator());
    }
}
final String finalString = stringBuilder.toString();
```