# Remove whole line by character index

Tags: java, string

I have a string like

```
String str = "<tr>\n
    <td class="tg-s6z2">@w1d1p7</td>\n
    <td class="tg-s6z2">@w1d2p7</td>\n
    <td class="tg-s6z2">@w1d3p7</td>\n
    <td class="tg-s6z2">@w1d4p7</td>\n
    <td class="tg-s6z2">@w1d5p7</td>\n
    <td class="tg-s6z2">@w1d6p7</td>\n
  </tr>\n"; //removed all backslashes (escapes) for readability.
```

What I need: remove the whole line which contains e.g. @w1d1p7. So the result is:

```
String str = "<tr>\n
    <td class="tg-s6z2">@w1d2p7</td>\n
    <td class="tg-s6z2">@w1d3p7</td>\n
    <td class="tg-s6z2">@w1d4p7</td>\n
    <td class="tg-s6z2">@w1d5p7</td>\n
    <td class="tg-s6z2">@w1d6p7</td>\n
  </tr>\n";
```

Thank you.

== Edit ==

Question is: I can find index of "@w1d1p7". How can I remove the whole line having this index?

Comment: You'll always want to show what you've tried

Comment: Maybe you should think about parsing your HTML content as...HTML content.  Then just search for the particular tag you want to remove, and remove it.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen task is about working with string in java.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Thank you Tim, but I've found this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28953054/removing-lines-from-a-string-containing-certain-character#28953226

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I mentioned in my comment above, if you want to do any serious manipulation of HTML content, you should be using an HTML/XML parser, rather than base string functions.  That being said, for your particular string, you can search for the following pattern and just replace with empty string:

```
<td class=\"tg-s6z2\">@w1d1p7</td>\n
```

Code snippet:

```
String str = "<tr>\n" +
    "<td class=\"tg-s6z2\">@w1d1p7</td>\n" +
    "<td class=\"tg-s6z2\">@w1d2p7</td>\n" +
    "<td class=\"tg-s6z2\">@w1d3p7</td>\n" +
    "<td class=\"tg-s6z2\">@w1d4p7</td>\n" +
    "<td class=\"tg-s6z2\">@w1d5p7</td>\n" +
    "<td class=\"tg-s6z2\">@w1d6p7</td>\n" +
    "</tr>\n";

str = str.replaceAll("<td class=\"tg-s6z2\">@w1d1p7</td>\n", "");
System.out.println(str);
```

Note that `String#replaceAll()` has regex capability, so if your replacing requirements were more complex than this, we probably could also accommodate them.

**Output:**

```
<tr>
<td class="tg-s6z2">@w1d2p7</td>
<td class="tg-s6z2">@w1d3p7</td>
<td class="tg-s6z2">@w1d4p7</td>
<td class="tg-s6z2">@w1d5p7</td>
<td class="tg-s6z2">@w1d6p7</td>
</tr>
```

**Demo here:**

## Rextester

Answer (score 1):

You would like to Split the string based on line breaks and then Look through each lines if they have the unwanted text. something like this...

```
public class HelloString {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    String str = "<tr>\n"+
            "<td class=\"tg-s6z2\">@w1d1p7</td>\n"+
            "<td class=\"tg-s6z2\">@w1d2p7</td>\n"+
            "<td class=\"tg-s6z2\">@w1d3p7</td>\n"+
            "<td class=\"tg-s6z2\">@w1d4p7</td>\n"+
            "<td class=\"tg-s6z2\">@w1d5p7</td>\n"+
            "<td class=\"tg-s6z2\">@w1d6p7</td>\n"+
            "</tr>\n";
    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
      String[] split = str.split("\\r?\\n|\\r");
      for (String s : split) {
          if (!s.contains("w1d1p7")) {
              builder.append(s);
          }
      }
      System.out.println(builder.toString());
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would split the String into an ArrayList using str.split("/n") [you split at every /n]

and then just delete the line you don't need